# Sending Integer from Processing to Arduino, bytes cannot be read

Tags: c++, function, arduino, integer, processing

I am trying to display 4 separate digits on my 7 segment display. These numbers are made from a program and Processing receives a number like 9561, and through math, I isolate 9 5 6 1 into individual digits.

since a single digit is 4 bits, I use an integer to sequentially compress the numbers, which in it's full decimal form appears to be 5721. I then send this integer to the Arduino, where I have 2 bytes sequencially running Serial.read();

My issue is that my 7 segment 4 digit display only displays 9500 meaning that x2 is 00 meaning that the 61 get lost in translation.

Even more so, when I speed up time (t) or the time for multiplexing, the 95 will flash over 00 and I confirmed it when I made seg0 and seg1 of the array 0 and 0.
When t = 3 this occurs, but anything higher than say, 8 doesn't have this issue.

I should also mention in my switch() the default case displays a 0.

**Processing**

```
void draw()
{
    seg[0] = 9;
    seg[1] = 5;
    seg[2] = 6;
    seg[3] = 1;


    int x = (seg[pos+3] & 0x000f)<<12|((seg[pos+2]) & 0x000f)<<8|(seg[pos+1] & 0x000f )<<4|((seg[pos] & 0x000f)); //3210

    myPort.write(x);

    //0123
    int disp1 = x;
    int disp2 = (x & 0x00f0)>>4;
    int disp3 = (x & 0x0f00)>>8;
    int disp4 = (x & 0xf000)>>12;

    //0123
    print(disp1, '\n', disp2, '\n', disp3, '\n', disp4, '\n', '\n');
}
```

**Arduino (Relevant areas, its a lot of code**

```
void digitdisplay(byte x,byte x2)
{
    //unsigned char tn = int (num/1000);
    //if (tn>10)
    //{
    //  tn = tn - 10;
    //}
    //
    //unsigned char hn = int (num/100)%10;
    //unsigned char tenn = int (num/10)%10;
    //unsigned char on = int (num%10);
    int disp[4];

    disp[0] = ( x & 0x0f);
    disp[1] = ( x & 0xf0)>>4;
    disp[2] = ( x2 & 0x0f);
    disp[3] = ( x2 & 0xf0)>>4;

    numberselect(disp[0]);
    digitselect(1);
    delay(t);

    numberselect(disp[1]);
    digitselect(2);
    delay(t);

    numberselect(disp[2]);
    digitselect(3);
    delay(t);

    numberselect(disp[3]);
    digitselect(4);
    delay(t);
}

void loop()
{
    int sen = analogRead(A0);
    int maxrange = (sen*maxval);
    byte x,x2;

    if (Serial.available()>2)
    { // If data is available to read,
        x=Serial.read();
        x2=Serial.read();
    }

    //shiftlight(maxrange);
    digitdisplay(x,x2);
}
```

Comment: Keep in mine, Arduino is C++ not Java.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing that `myPort` is an `OutputStream`, your one invocation of `myPort.write(int)` writes just one byte, extracted from the lowest-order 8 bits of its argument.  The higher-order bits are lost.  That's why you're seeing only the 9 and 5.

I cannot explain from the code presented why you display 9500 instead of 9595, but that seems consistent with your claim that at higher update rates you see the 95 alternating with 00.  Both lead me to think that some other part of your code is writing zeroes to the serial port.

Comment: I get it, it's just kind of annoying that there's no indications with it. The max value of integer that can be send is 256.

So I should have two separate bytes on the Processing side just like how I have 2 on the receiving side?

Comment: @AdamKujawinski, two separate one-byte writes would be a reasonable way to go about it.  I would consider it a bonus that that would match up better with the reading side, so I'll not go into any alternatives.

Comment: OK, so it seems like Processing is not allowing me to compile into 2 separate bytes, so I pack it into 2 separate integers. I'll keep you updated :)

Answer (score 0):

Java's String representation is UTF-16. That means that each character is represented by 2 bytes. For ASCII-letters one of them is 0x00. This could be the reason why you don't get the `61` out of the stream at the expected position.

You can either skip each second byte on the Arduino or convert the characters to plain ASCII before sending using `getBytes(Charset charset)` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html